# Adding keys in one JavaScript Object to another only if the first object doesn't have those keys

Tags: javascript

```
function extend(obj1, obj2) {

  var obj2Keys = Object.keys(obj2);
  var obj2Values = Object.values(obj2);

  var obj1Keys = Object.keys(obj1);
  var obj1Values = Object.keys(obj1);
  
  var newObj = {};

  for(var i=0; i<obj1Keys.length; i++) {
    if(obj1Keys[i] !== obj2Keys[i]) {
      

    }
  }
  
}

var obj1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
};
var obj2 = {
  b: 4,
  c: 3
};

extend(obj1, obj2);

console.log(obj1); // --> {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
console.log(obj2); // --> {b: 4, c: 3}

/*

 1. Add any keys that are not in the 1st object.
 2. If the 1st object already has a given key, ignore it  (do not
    overwrite the property value).
 3. Do not modify the 2nd object at all.

*/
```

Hey guys, trying to figure this one out. I'm sure i'm doing this the most inefficient way. I'm struggling to compare indexes of these objects.. Any help?? I was using for in loops originally but I couldn't conceptually understand what I was doing lol. Kinda stuck at this point.

Comment: `Object.assign({}, second, first)` - overwriting second's keys by the first's.

Comment: Is it a requirement that the original object is mutated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get `keys` of `obj2`
2. Iterate over them using the `for-loop`
3. In each iteration, if `obj1` does not have this `key`, and the record to it from `obj2`

```js
function extend (obj1, obj2) {
  const obj2Keys = Object.keys(obj2);
  for(let i = 0; i < obj2Keys.length; i++) {
    const currentKey = obj2Keys[i]
    if(!obj1[currentKey]) {
      obj1[currentKey] = obj2[currentKey];
    }
  }
}

const obj1 = { a: 1, b: 2 }; const obj2 = { b: 4, c: 3 };

extend(obj1, obj2);

console.log(obj1); // --> {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
console.log(obj2); // --> {b: 4, c: 3}
```

Another way using [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
function extend (obj1, obj2) {
  Object.keys(obj2).forEach(currentKey => {
    if(!obj1[currentKey]) {
      obj1[currentKey] = obj2[currentKey];
    }
  });
}

const obj1 = { a: 1, b: 2 }; const obj2 = { b: 4, c: 3 };

extend(obj1, obj2);

console.log(obj1); // --> {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
console.log(obj2); // --> {b: 4, c: 3}
```

Comment: How is if(!obj1[currentKey]) different from if(obj1[currentKey] !== obj2[currentKey])



why do I get the right answer with the first statement and the wrong value with the second?

Comment: ``!obj1[currentKey]`` means that ``obj1`` has no such ``key``. ``obj1[currentKey] !== obj2[currentKey]`` means that for the key ``currentKey``, the``values`` from ``obj1`` and ``obj2`` are different. In your case, you want to only add a key-value pair from ``obj2`` to ``obj1`` if it doesn't exist in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

```js
const firstObject = {a:1,b:2,c:3}
const secondObject = {a:11,b:22,c:33,d:44}
var newObject = {...secondObject,...firstObject}

console.log(newObject)
```

result:

```
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":44}
```

Comment: This is identical to my answer

Comment: no, your answer is different.

your output will be : 

{"a":11,"b":22,"c":33,"d":44}

Comment: @symlink "only if the first object doesn't have those keys".

Comment: Slightly different output, identical method.

Comment: but he is asking, not to replace the values of the first object

Comment: Oh you're right, I see the distinction now.

Answer (score 1):

Use the spread syntax to combine the objects. The spread syntax basically inserts the objects key/value pairs wherever you write it, so you're creating a new object with `{...obj1, ...obj2}`. If there are pairs with duplicate keys, the pair from the second object will be selected.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

```js
let obj1 = {a: 1, b: 2}
let obj2 = {b: 4, c: 3}

let obj3 = {...obj2, ...obj1}
console.log(obj3)
```

Comment: I agree this is the most readable and simple way. However I think you should put ...obj1 last so it grabs its values on the shared keys

Comment: @FabioLopez yeah, it depends on which object's values he wants to take precedence. He didn't say so I used the second one, but explained how he could use either one by putting it last.

Comment: @symlink your answer is different. your script output will be : {"a":11,"b":22,"c":33,"d":44}